# Ubuntu 20.04: location services not working

Tags: 20.04, location, top-bar, google-maps

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and now, while Location Services are enabled in the Settings, I do not see the location icon in my top bar, and services requiring my location cannot retrieve it.

See it is enabled in Settings:

[image: pic1]

But my top bar does not have the location icon that used to show there:

[image: pic2]

And services like Google Maps do not seem to be able to retrieve my location. See below in Firefox, even though I allowed it...

[image: pic3]

[image: pic4]

Any clue? I use Google maps on my laptop quite frequently, so it is quite important to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tha Arch Linux wiki helped me out with this issue. Can you try this?

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox#Geolocation_does_not_work

TL;DR:

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Search for `geo.provider.network.url`
3. Replace with `https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=%MOZILLA_API_KEY%`

Comment: This seems to work! the location isn't super accurate (just across the road so within 50m I guess), but at least I get something now! Thanks

Comment: is it supposed to be the literal %MOZILLA_API_KEY% or an actual key? are there any further steps required to apply this change?